# Regarding strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

I am a beginner in C and I tried writing a function which was supposed to return a string, but when I try to print the result obtained from the function, I only get `(null)`

Here's my code:

```
char *reverse(char *str) {
    char result[20];

    /* logic */

    return result;
}

int main() {
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
    printf("The string reversed is: %s", reverse(str));
}
```

Why does this print `(null)`, when I have noticed that something like this works just fine:

```
char *func() {
    return "hello";
}

int main() {
    printf("%s", func());
}
```

Comment: The function `reverse` returns the address of the local variable `result`. Maybe the logic fails to set the new value to `result`?

Answer (score 1):

The function `reverse()` returns a pointer to an array defined with local scope in the body of the function: this array goes out of scope when the function returns and the pointer becomes invalid (a dangling pointer). Reading from an invalid pointer has undefined behavior. It is surprising that `printf` outputs `(null)` for this, but undefined behavior means anything can happen, don't be surprised, don't expect the same behavior the next time, it is vain to try and explain the actual observed behavior.

You should make the array `static` or allocate it from the heap or better, take the destination array as an argument.

Also be aware that `scanf("%[^\n]s", str)` is incorrect:

- the trailing `s` is meaningless and should be removed ;
- the maximum number of characters to store into `str` should be specified to avoid a potential buffer overflow: `scanf("%19[^\n]", str)`
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input, such as an empty line.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char *result, const char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result[i] = str[len - 1 - i];
    }
    result[len] = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char str[20];
    char output[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (scanf("%19[^\n]", str) == 1) {
        printf("The string reversed is: %s\n", reverse(output, str));
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! That could be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your snippet is printing (null) is because you are returning a local array result from the reverse function, which is a stack-allocated array. Once the reverse function returns, the memory for the result array is deallocated, and you are left with a dangling pointer. Accessing this pointer leads to undefined behavior, and in your case, it happens to print (null).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* reverse(const char* str) {
    int length = strlen(str);
    char* result = (char*)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (result == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = str[length - 1 - i];
    }
    result[length] = '\0';

    return result;
}

int main() {
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", str);  // Limit input length to avoid buffer overflow
    char* reversed = reverse(str);
    printf("The string reversed is: %s\n", reversed);

    // Don't forget to free the dynamically allocated memory when done
    free(reversed);

    return 0;
}
```

1. We dynamically allocate memory for the result string using malloc.
   The length of the string is determined by strlen(str), and we add 1
   to accommodate the null-terminator.
2. We copy the characters from the input string str in reverse order
   into the dynamically allocated result string.
3. We make sure to null-terminate the result string.
4. After using the reversed string, it is important to free the
   dynamically allocated memory using free to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Are you aware that the corrected program will still have undefined behavior if the user hits enter on an empty line?

Comment: @Jeevan ebi, Aside: `char* result = (char*)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));` simpler as `char* result = malloc(length + 1);`